# Fluent NHibernate - HasMany mapping with condition

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a HasMany mapping that needs a condition.  I have this partially working, but there's got to be a better way than what I'm doing.  The condition I'm using needs to look at a property on another table that I'm joining to.  What I have so far is:

```
    HasMany<MetaData>(x => x.MetaData).Table("MetaData")
        .KeyColumn("DefinitionID")
        .KeyColumn("TableID")
        .Where("metadatade1_.SourceTable = 'Providers'")
        .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

In the code above, the where clause is referencing "metadatade1_", because it's trying to fully qualify the name, and that is the name NH is generating.  I've tried using "MetaDataDefinitions.SourceTable" (MetaDataDef... is the physical table name), and also just "SourceTable" by itself, however none of these worked.

Is there a way to not have it try and fully qualify the name on the condition and just pass "SourceTable='Providers'"  OR is there a way I can have it reference the generated name without me having to manually plug it in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. The `Where` method (and respectively the `where=` attribute in HBM.XML) accept only *raw sql*, and as such is prone to the problems you're seeing.

Your best option is to not use a collection and instead rely on a query to retrieve your metadata instances.

Comment: Not exactly was I was hoping for, but thanks for the answer! I'll take your advice and build a query to retrieve this data.